# Can't properly initiate Reader object

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read a file. so in my class 'Skanner' i have a field that looks like this:

`private Reader reader, readerX;`

Now I initialized these fields in the contructor:

```
public Skanner()
    {   
        try 
        {
            Reader readerX = new FileReader("aliceinwonderland.txt");
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(readerX);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

but when I try to use the fields in methods of class Skanner, I get a null-pointer exception. If I instead use `reader.read()` in the try block of the constructor that doesn't give any problems. Why can't I call `reader.read()` outside the scope where I initiated it?

Comment: Please provide the specific code to reproduce the problem. Do not explain your code problem in plain words only.

Comment: Please post more code, at least the problematic line (causing the NPE), and the full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're hiding the instance members by redeclaring them in the method. Remove the Reader type declarations from the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the `Reader` object is only available in your contructor which is

```
public Skanner()
    {   
        try 
        {
            Reader readerX = new FileReader("aliceinwonderland.txt");
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(readerX);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

if you would like to access them outside the constructor you need to declare them outside the constructor

```
 Reader readerX;
 Reader reader;

 public Skanner()
        {   
            try 
            {
                  readerX= new FileReader("aliceinwonderland.txt");
                  reader = new BufferedReader(readerX);
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

public void someMethod(){
//is now available
// make sure you use new Skanner() first before calling this method or it will result to NPE(null pointer exception) because the initialization of reader is in the constructor
reader.read();
}
```

and if you want to access them outside the class use the `public` access modifier.